# Find out where a multi-threading C# program is stuck

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have written a C# program having some thousand lines and several threads. Execution works fine for several hours/days until the application, which is running on a Windows server, starts to slow everything (other programs/web server) down as it suddenly begins to use up about 50-80% of the CPU.

I assume that it is stuck in some while-loop, but I do not know where exactly. It would already be a help to know which thread uses up the largest share of the system resources. As there is not any exception thrown, I do not see any direct possibility to find out.

The code has already been inspected but I did not find any significant/obvious programming mistakes.

Does anybody know a good way to let Visual Studio monitor the current CPU-load in order to show where it is used up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh, how I love Managed Stack Explorer. http://mse.codeplex.com/ for most versions of .NET and https://github.com/vadimskipin/MSE for 4.0

Point it at your running application, and it snapshots the stacks of each thread. After looking at a few snapshots, you'll work out where the problem is. Oh, the nastiness of the problem I was facing when I first learnt of this. Oh the joy when it let me find what I'd been hunting for days in just a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using MSE now. Now I'll have to wait for my program to get stuck again ;)

Comment: And again thank you so much. I had been searching for days to find out, why it got stuck. Now I have used CLR Stack Explorer for .Net 4.0 (as the compilation of the patched MSE failed), which even gave me the exact line of code being executed when I inspected the execution of my program today again. That is much more than I have expected.

Comment: I had the same experience when I first used it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Perfview (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) to capture and the analyse ETL traces when this happens.